# Running ant.java inside Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle

I am creating my own gradle plugin.

in my MyRunTask which extends DefaultTask

I am writing something like this

```
@TaskAction
public void run() {

    ant.java {
        main = 'org.mylang.runtime.main.Main'
        classpath = project.configurations.runtime
        args = [
            project.mylang.mainMylangClass
        ]
        classpath jar.archivePath

    }
}
```

run is linked with Jar task so i can directly use the jar while running my program. For this reason i like to lick Jar to my ant.java

1. I want to link my run taks depends to Jar task so i can use the jar directly to my run
2. when i give `classpath jar.archivePath`  its saying `jar` is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use Gradle's `project.javaexec` instead of Ant's `project.ant.java`. Instead of hardcoding `project.jar.archivePath`, your task class should accept a property `classpath` of type `Iterable<File>` that gets configured with `jar.archivePath` from outside (either by a plugin or by a build script). If all that your task class does is to execute `project.javaexec`, consider using a regular `JavaExec` task that gets configured by a plugin or build script.

Comment: >> "should accept a property classpath of type Iterable<File> that gets configured with jar.archivePath from outside"    Will this happen automatically ?  without using jar.archivePath ?

Comment: No, you'll have to do it either in a custom plugin or in a build script. The point is that task classes shouldn't know about the build model. Otherwise they are too tightly coupled and not reusable.